# Search for value and return row number

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm struggle with this script. I need to search for today date, once match it return column number (done!). I need a script to do the same with row number. The script I have is works fine if I keep only one table on that sheet, but I have more tables and if I use values.length -1 will return last row from the sheet. Also, every table might not have a fixed row numbers, so need to be dynamic.

This is the script I have so far:

```
function getTodaysTotal() {
  function toDateFormat(date) {
try {return date.setHours(0,0,0,0);}
catch(e) {return;}
 }

var values = SpreadsheetApp
  .openById("id")
  .getSheetByName("Q3 - W27 - 39")
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();


var today = toDateFormat(new Date());
var todaysColumn = values[5].map(toDateFormat).map(Number).indexOf(+today);
var output = values[values.length - 1][todaysColumn];
var emailDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today),"GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

And that's a screen shoot of my table.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQRxJ.png)

Hope it make sense. I have the column number and I need to find row number that contain Total.

Thank you!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through an array of data which is probably the fastest.

Have a look at the below script and implement in your existing.

Not sure if it is only one column where you are looking but for example column C:

```
for (i in values){
if (values[i][2]=='Total'){
Logger.log(i);
var nr = i
   }
}
```

var nr now contains i as the row number it found the word "Total" in column C (the #2 after [i]).

you can then use the variable in anything that you would like after the first closing bracket.

Comment: I keep getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property "32" from undefined. (line 25, file "Utils")

Comment: Some variable is currently undefined in your script. The script that I have put in above must be embedded in your full script including the variables used. Use the debug and the logger. What is line 25 in the code?? Share your sheet and full code.

Comment: So line 25 is variable output and the property is probably the row number returned from the IF statement. It seems that you keep the rest of your script within the if statement loop. Make sure you close the IF statement before going further. The IF statement is there to assign the variable but if you don't close the IF statement before using that variable it will be undefined. Close that loop first and try again. Put a '}' below the variable Newnr.

Comment: Still getting errors ... Here's a copy of my file ... I need to get first total (row number) ... https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Of2qpfaz8Z8sAhblVP1ebllHR3WT7b3kEehli6xqe0U

Answer (score 0):

I add this to my script, but I get undefined on output. I get the right value if I use logger log, but I also get an empty value (undefined). So I need only the first value.

```
function getTodaysTotal() {
 function toDateFormat(date) {
try {return date.setHours(0,0,0,0);}
catch(e) {return;}
   }

var values = SpreadsheetApp
  .openById("id")
  .getSheetByName("Q3 - W27 - 39")
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();

for (i in values){
 if (values[i][0]=='Total'){
 var nr = i;
 var newNr = parseInt(nr);

 //       Logger.log(nr);


var today = toDateFormat(new Date());
var todaysColumn = 
 values[5].map(toDateFormat).map(Number).indexOf(+today);
var output = values[newNr][todaysColumn];
 Logger.log(output);
var emailDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today),"GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
//   Logger.log(todaysColumn);
//    Logger.log(output);
// return values[values.length - 1][todaysColumn];
}
 }




 if (output == undefined) {
GmailApp.sendEmail("email@company.com", "test data", "Today, " +emailDate +" we had no calls made or no values are inputed.");   
 }
 else if (output == "") {
GmailApp.sendEmail("email@company.com", "test data", "Today, " +emailDate +" we had no calls made or no values are inputed.");
}
 else {

GmailApp.sendEmail("email@company.com", "test data", "Today, " +emailDate +" we had " +output + " calls made.");

}
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access google drive at my place now. It seems that if you get the right value and an empty value your variable todaysColumn is probably empty. Change your logger to variable todaysColumn to understand what the value is. It seems you won't be able to map to numbers after you have mapped it to (toDateFormat). What is the reason you want to both?